# How to execute an animation in Javascript using the Raphael Library using a mouse click or a mouse drag?

Tags: javascript, raphael

What I want is to be able to signal this movement using a mouse click or drag to the desire position

```
var drawingArea = Raphael(10,10,400,400);
var circle = drawingArea.circle(200,200,15);
circle.attr({fill:'blue', stroke:'red'});
var animation = Raphael.animation({cx:30, cy:30}, 5000);
circle.animate(animation);
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried the solution I posted? Are you having any trouble with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event handlers:](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click)

```
circle.click(function() {
    circle.animate(animation);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag it to a desired position following a drag from the mouse, you need to manipulate its coordinates (instead of using animations).
The [drag()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag) function allows you to set up callbacks for the events of start dragging, end dragging and move while dragging.

One technique for doing that is storing the original positions on start and updating it on move:

```
var start = function () {
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
};
var move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
};
circle.drag(move, start);
```

You can see [an example code using this on the Raphael.js website](http://raphaeljs.com/touches.html).